# How do I get Python to print from 1 to user input?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve the scenario with these conditions:

1. Ask the user to enter a number
2. Count up from 1 to the number that the user has entered, displaying each number on    its own line if it is an odd number. If it is an even number, do not display the number.
3. If the user enters a number that is 0 or less, display error

My codes are as follows and I can't seem to satisfy the <= 0 print("error) condition:

```
   num=int(input("Enter number: "))
     for x in range(num):
      if x % 2 == 0:
         continue
      print(x)
       elif x<=0:
         print("error")
```

Comment: You do not check the number entered against 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will be :

```
num=int(input("Enter number: "))
if num <= 0:
    print("Error")
else:
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            continue
        print(i)
```

You need to print the error before looping from 1 to num because if the value is less the 0 then the loop won't run. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the condition `num <= 0` as soon as the user enters the number:

```py
num = int(input("Enter number: "))
if num <= 0:
    print("error")
else:
    for x in range(num):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            continue
        print(x)
```